# Android Workmanager PeriodicWorkRequest is not unique

Tags: android-workmanager

For OneTimeWorkRequest we can use WorkContinuation to ensure that if the job is already scheduled we can KEEP or REPLACE it.
There is no such option for PeriodicWorkRequest, so every time my main activity is created a new job is created and after a while I get this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apps may not schedule more than 100 distinct jobs
```

So I'm trying the following to create a "unique peiodic work"

```
public void schedule(){
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true).build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest zombieSpawnWorker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ZombieSpawnWorker
            .class).setInitialDelay(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setConstraints(constraints).addTag(ZombieSpawnWorker.TAG).build();
    this.setUuid(zombieSpawnWorker.getId());
    WorkManager.getInstance().beginUniqueWork(TAG,
                    ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                    OneTimeWorkRequest.from(ZombieSpawnWorker.class));
}
```

And then calling this method again at the end of the work

```
public WorkerResult doWork() {
    try {
        //work to be done
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return WorkerResult.FAILURE;
    }
    schedule();
    return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IllegalStateException` you see was a bug we fixed in `alpha01`. Use the `alpha02` library, and you won't see that problem. For more information, take a look at the release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes).

Comment: Thank you. We had updated to alpha02 and observe it again. May I know, for one time worker, at the end of its execution, do we need to explicitly cancel tag, to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: Also, we are using WorkManager to perform alarm reminder scheduling. Having limitation "Apps may not schedule more than 100 distinct jobs", does that means `WorkManager` is not suitable to schedule more than 100 reminders?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Have you found any solution for more than 100 job exception.

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround is to add a tag `REQUEST_TAG` to the `PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder`, and then call `WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag(REQUEST_TAG)` before you enqueue the periodic request.