# Android Worker execute the job multiple times

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, countdownlatch, android-workmanager

I use the following code to schedule a background job execute every 15 mins.

```
WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
PeriodicWorkRequest ulpBackup;

ulpBackup = new PeriodicWorkRequest
    .Builder(Ulp.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .addTag(activity.getString(R.string.job_tag))
    .build();
workManager.enqueue(ulpBackup);
```

And here is the UlpBackup.class

```
public class UlpBackup extends Worker {
    private Integer responseCounter = 0;

    public UlpBackup() {}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        Log.d(logTag, "Starting periodic backup job";   
        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        /** Read from local database and upload to firestore **/

        localdb.setAPIListener(new APIListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnSuccess() {
                responseCounter++;
                if (responseCounter == 5) {
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void OnFailure() {
                responseCounter++;
                if (responseCounter == 5) {
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }
            }
        });

        localdb.sync();

        try {
            countDownLatch.await(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(logTag, "Error in user list backup job " + exception.getMessage());
            return Result.FAILURE;
        }

        Log.e(logTag, "Ulp backup completed");
        return Result.SUCCESS;
}
```

The above code works fine and the job happened roughly every 15 minutes as expected. The only thing that I do not understand is that every time the job execute multiple times, can someone explain why and how can i avoid it?

From the log:

```
09-15 23:33:37.514 8190-8410: Starting periodic backup job
09-15 23:33:37.520 8190-8414: Starting periodic backup job
09-15 23:33:37.561 8190-8412: Starting periodic backup job
09-15 23:33:37.568 8190-8413: Starting periodic backup job
...
...
09-15 23:33:38.183 8190-8414: Ulp backup completed
09-15 23:33:39.164 8190-8412: Ulp backup completed
09-15 23:33:39.580 8190-8413: Ulp backup completed
09-15 23:38:37.517 8190-8410: Ulp backup completed
```

Comment: Does this also happen after a fresh install of your app? Maybe you enqueued the job multiple times...

Comment: @HedeH you are correct, seems like fresh install the apps work. Looks like the problem is i keep reloading the app which run enqueue every time i reload it. I add a protection logic as shown here to avoid such problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612274/check-if-workmanager-is-scheduled-already  Thanks for helping!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this following method : `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()`, and implement like that :

```
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("YOUR_TAG", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, workRequest);
```

Please notice that the second parameter is the key. The enum can be `KEEP` or `REPLACE`

Answer (score -4):

I think i am late to answer this question and you might have tweaked it too.. But i am trying to help anyways..

> The only thing that I do not understand is that every time the job execute multiple times, `can someone explain` why and how can i avoid it?

### Explanation :

Everyone will be shocked if i will say :

1. Googles android has no control over crores of processes running in real-time basis
2. It even lacks to understand even say xyz process is completed? or running? or finished?
3. This is it. And the outcome is the your issue

> Oh my god.. It will lead to `data-loss` if i am doing any database operations then..!!??

Yes it results in data loss many times..

> Does android and developers have any work around then...?

Yes, Prefer using `IntentService`.

> What is so special in `IntentService`?

If a `intentservice` is already running and even if `thousands` of times it gets called... Then in that case too... all calls are kept in `queue` by android and processed `one by one` and `one after another` and after one is `finished` then only another waiting `awakes` and starts to execute it

Hope it helps.

Comment: startService will no longer work on devices on Android 8.0 come November 1st, so I don't recommend this. For the asker, refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435131/android-workmanager-periodicworkrequest-is-not-unique