# How to set Wallpaper automatically everyday in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application that shows the different photos from server and user can set select photos as wallpaper of its device i used given code to set wallpaper it working but i want to wallpaper set automatically every day. I used this code.

Java

```
 private void setAsWallpaper()
    {
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(new Target()
        {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
            {
                progressBar.bringToFront();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(SetWallPaperFullScreenActivity.this);
                try
                {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(SetWallPaperFullScreenActivity.this, "Wallpaper set successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable)
            {
                Log.d("TAG", "Failed: ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
            {
                Log.d("TAG", "Prepare Load: ");

            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: try work manager to run code every day https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083407/2633909

Comment: Here is a great document you can use of [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14980699/4527628)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) first you need to Schedule job which  called every 24 hour. reference [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

2) now use below method to set wallpaper

```
 public void setWallpaper {
          WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = 
                      WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.wallpaper);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

Create a sticky service as shown below then i have created a TimerTask(Scheduler) which will run after every 24hrs there you can add your code for setting wallpaper. Don't forget to register the service in Manifest. Start this service from any activity.

[You can refer the sticky service from here to know more](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startTimer();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask();
    //schedule the timer, after the first **5000ms** the TimerTask will run in every **24hrs**
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 86400000);
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //ToDo set wallapaper here
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```